# fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git error after remove xcode

Tags: git

Here is the scenario:

i uninstalled xcode and git removed by uninstalling , my local commits are gone. but i can see .git folder in my project and it is not empty.

when i run any commands of git it says : **fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git**

also when i run `git init` i get this : **error: failed to write new configuration file /Users/myuser/Desktop/xxxproject/.git/config.lock
fatal: could not set 'core.repositoryformatversion' to '0'**

is there any way to recover commits? :)

Comment: Sounds like you don't have permissions to read from (or write to) the .git folder from the shell. Or maybe only to some critical files in it.

Comment: @fredrik so is there any solutions?

Comment: Fix the permissions if that's the issue - I don't know how to do that in a MacOS system though.

Comment: chmod in terminal, to change your permission. but uninstalling xcode shouldn't delete your local commits. are you sure you're running from the same folder that the .git folder lies in?

Comment: @A-_-S yes the path is correct.
i got the permission by **sudo chmod -R u+rwx .git** and now i can run git commands but still cannot recover changes. for example when i run ```git status``` i get this : **error: short read while indexing .gitignore** and same error for some other files

Comment: I'm not sure how to help you out here, but maybe update your question, since you don't get anymore the `fatal: not ...` message.